# Why am I getting java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java

System.out.println("enter maze");

```
    char[][] maze = new char[height][width];
    for (int i=0;i<height;i++){
        String line= scanner.nextLine();
        for (int j=0;j<width;j++){
            maze[i][j]= line.charAt(j);

        }
    }
```

Comment: what are the values of height, width and line?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is from the line `maze[i][j]= line.charAt(j);` because the input from `scanner` is not guaranteed to be of length `j`.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being thrown by `line.charAt(j)`, and it is telling you that it cannot get the first character (at position 0) of `line` ... which means that `line` is empty.

Reading your code, it is making the assumption that the input consists of (at least) `height` lines each of which contains (at least) `width` characters.

I can think of two possible root causes for the exception:

1. One of the input lines could really be empty.
2. You could be getting an empty line because of how you handled the `Scanner` *before* this code.  For example, if you previously called `nextInt` to get read the values of `height` and `width`, the line separator after those numbers would be left in the scanner's input.  So the next call to `nextLine` would deliver the rest of *that* line ... which is probably an empty string.